# Correct date/time from XML to local date/time using JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an XML tag with the following data from the open-weather API for the sunrise and sunset in Melbourne:

```
<sun rise="2020-11-13T19:00:49" set="2020-11-14T09:08:32"/>
```

Which is wrong as the sun can't rise at 19:00 hours. I assume is because it is on UTC hours and the API is just doing some sort weird conversion.

**I just want to fix the sunrise and sunset time to show the correct time.**

This is my code:

```
 xml.find("sun").each( function(){

                        var riseTime = new Date( $(this).attr("rise"));

                        var setTime = new Date( $(this).attr("set"));

                        strSunRise += riseTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-AU')+ "<br />";
                        strSunSet += setTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-AU')+ "<br />";

                        document.getElementById("sunRise").innerHTML = strSunRise;
                        document.getElementById("sunSet").innerHTML = strSunSet;
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like openweathermap API has a timezone tag as well - seconds as offset from UTC. Maybe something like this works?

```
xml.find("city").each((i, city) => {
    let sun = city.find("sun");
    let timeZoneSeconds = +city.find("timezone").text();
    let riseTime = new Date(new Date(sun.attr("rise")) + timeZoneSeconds);
    let setTime = new Date(new Date(sun.attr("set")) + timeZoneSeconds);
    // riseTime and setTime are now in local time
});
```